# C++ using push_back in a mouse callback function

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write some code to plan a path for a robot by clicking on points in an image and storing them in a vector of points. Each time the mouse is clicked I want to use push_back to increase the size of the vector and append the new point to the end. My code is as follows:

```
void planPath(cv::Mat& src) 
{

     vector<Point2f> path_checkpoints;

     //Create a window
     namedWindow("Draw path", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
     //show the image
     imshow("Draw path", src);
      //set the callback function for any mouse event
     setMouseCallback("Draw path", CallBackFunc2, (void*)&path_checkpoints);

     // Wait until user press some key
     waitKey(0);
}
```

And the callback function:

```
//Mouse callback function
void CallBackFunc2(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* ptr)
{
    Point2f *p = (Point2f*)ptr;
    static int i = 0;

    while(waitKey(10) != 32) 
    {
        if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN ) //Accept new points until space is pressed
        {
                p.push_back(Point(x,y));

                cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
        }
    }
    destroyWindow("Draw path");
}
```

The error i'm getting is at this line:

```
p.push_back(Point(x,y));
```

"Expression must have class type"

My understanding is that I cant use push_back because the callback function is only passed one point, not the whole vector. Is it possible to pass the vector of points into the callback function?

Comment: Did you mean to write `std::vector<Point2f> p;` instead of `Point2f *p`?

Comment: Point2f *p = (Point2f*)ptr; // that's a pointer, not a vector. also, decide, if you want to use Point or Point2f

Comment: Another problem is that `path_checkpoints` vector goes out of scope, after returning from the `planPath()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ptr` is pointing to a `vector<Point2f>`, *not* a `Point2f`, you should cast it to `vector<Point2f> *`:

```
vector<Point2f> *p = static_cast<vector<Point2f> *>(ptr);
```

`p` is a pointer, so you must dereference it to access `vector<Point2f>` members:

```
p->push_back(Point2f(x,y))
```